Does Questrade only work with banks listed in the Interac portal for transfers?
I use a Wealthsimple account as my savings and Questrade for investments. How do I transfer a little money from Wealthsimple Cash account to Questrade?
Options like bill payment could take a few days, is there a way to do it at interac speed? i.e. in a few minutes?
Note, although Questrade does allow interac deposit, my understanding is that it only works with banks listed in the Interac portal because of the request workflow, am I mistaken?
